# Changing background in edittext results in making the width of the box equal to 0

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a large 7 by 15 tablelayout grid of edittexts and when I try to change any textbox background from "@android:color/transparent" to any colour, it squishes the whole row and distorts the entire grid. Here is the code for a typical textbox:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/a1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:editable="false"
                android:foreground="#801E8C1B"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: Try removing the alpha line code

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change your edit text with the following XML snippet which works for me. It creates three EditText views in a TableLayout row. Maybe as Android Studio suggest instead of `android:editable="false"` use `android:inputType="none"` and then change this attribute in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:foreground="#801E8C1B"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:foreground="#801E8C1B"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/a3"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:foreground="#801E8C1B"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```